# Find the point at which they separate in an SHM?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image: For the section b]

In the given problem, I can understand that after placing the two blocks in equilibrium it oscillates with an amplitude,

$$A=\frac{2}{k}(m_1+m_2)g\sin\phi$$

The answer for (b) is given as

$$\frac{1}{k}(m_1+m_2)g\sin\phi$$

To my knowledge, $m_2$ will separate from $m_1$ when the acceleration is greater than $g\sin\phi$ and so they should be separating only at max displacement on the right side as the $m_1$ retraces its path after imparting the greatest acceleration to $m_2$. So shouldn't the answer be $\frac{2}{k}(m_1+m_2)g\sin\phi$  on the right? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It asks for the speed

Comment: No, (b)- it asks the position where the m2 is released

Comment: oh yeah decent, your answer looks right

Comment: I believe the position is measured from the initial decompressed position (without masses) of the spring, not from the maximum compressed one.

Comment: Try to calculate the constraint force (acceleration free)  between m1 and m2 , put it equal zero and calculate the position

Comment: Yeah, the position is measured from the initially compressed state. It then goes left and after that towards right. But the answer confuses me. If it were to separate at 1/k(m1+m2)gsinø then that would be the max.displacement possible instead of the max. Displacement that they gave as 2/k(m1+m2)gsinø